# Set Value in MagicSuggest dynamically

Tags: jquery, multi-select, magicsuggest

I am using MagicSuggest for multiselect textbox with dropdown.I don't know how to set values dynamically.I have tried

```
var ms =$('#fruits').magicSuggest({
    //placeholder: 'Type some real or fake fruits',
    //toggleOnClick: true,
    //selectFirst:true,
    expandOnFocus: true,
    useTabKey: true,
    autoSelect: false,
    data: ['Banana','Mango','Apple','Orange']
});
   ms.setValue(['Banana']);
```

The above code works fine.But I want to change the value dynamically based on other textbox value.I have tried,

```
var ms1=$('#fruits').magicSuggest({});
ms1.setValue(['banana']);  

$('#fruits').val(['Banana']);

var m=$('#fruits').magicSuggest({value:['Banana']});
```

These three solutions are not working.Please Help....

Regards,
Rekha

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
 ms.addToSelection('banana',false);
```

Comment: I made a miskate in the object creation .I globally declared the variable ms and then set the value using ms.setValue in another function and it worked.